# SQL Server DB Backups WaitTypes

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am backing up a database to a network drive.

I am seeing the below Wait types for the backup. I have also tried backing up to a local drive and same issue (though backup does run much quicker). What is the backup waiting on?

[image]

Comment: Writing to disk. How slow is the network you're writing to? What type of drive(s)? http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/cause-high-duration-async_io_completion-waits/

Comment: How do I find network speed/drive types? This is the result of the backup... BACKUP DATABASE successfully processed 9212697 pages in 2083.974 seconds (34.536 MB/sec).

Comment: The backup took 35mins but the RESTORE VERIFYONLY took 45mins!

Comment: Ask your network and/or SAN administrator. You could be on 10GB or 1GB fiber, or worse, 100 or 10. You could be going over a very busy network connection with not a lot of headroom. The drives on the other end could be SSD/PCIe but sounds more like they are old-fashioned SATA. Ask what the RAID configuration is, and what sort of contention might be happening there. No way for us to know how your hardware is configured, but this definitely sounds like it's inadequate.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: the link you gave seems to indicate that _writing_ to disk would be the `BACKUPIO` wait type, whereas the `ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION` is caused by reading from the data files.   With a `BACKUPIO` wait of 9ms and a `ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION` wait of 165422ms, I'm confused as to how you conclude it's _writing_ to disk that's causing the wait.  Can you elaborate?  From the stats posted I would have concluded the backup destination speed is irrelevant, because the disk the data files reside on is too slow.

Comment: Please notice that Paul's post says ***A cause***, not ***The only cause***. I was pointing out that post so you could see how you could try to determine the cause ***in your case***, since I can't do that. My guess at slow network or destination disk is primarily because you stated that the backup is much faster when you run it locally. Some of the async waits might be from merely reading the data files, but if that was *all* of it, then you wouldn't see faster local performance. (It sounds like you should backup locally then copy, regardless of the outcome of this investigation.)

Comment: @k09 check the network card settings as well - **full duplex** or half duplex. I have seen that been a huge bottleneck and sometimes overlooked as being so obvious.